# Arduino UNO LoRa SX1278 not sending/receiving data correctly

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, lora

When I upload the code to try 2-way communication of LoRa Sx1278 with Arduino UNO it fails to work. I am using 2 modules with the same code. This is the output I receive:

> 23:09:27.186 -> Received packet:  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^' with RSSI -70
> 23:09:28.207 -> Sending message

I understand the module receives a message but fails to read it, and the second LoRa module with the receiver code fails.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

String outgoing;
byte msgCount = 0;            // count of outgoing messages
byte localAddress = 0xBB;     // address of this device
byte destination = 0xFF;      // destination to send to
long lastSendTime = 0;        // last send time
int interval = 300;          // interval between sends

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("LoRa Two-Way Communication");
  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    delay(100);
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastSendTime > interval) {
    String message = "data from sensors";
    Serial.println("Sending message");
  sendMessage(message);
    // Serial.println("Sending " + message);
    lastSendTime = millis(); // timestamp the message
    interval = random(50) + 300; // 2-3 seconds
  }
  // parse for a packet, and call onReceive with the result:
  onReceive(LoRa.parsePacket());
}

void sendMessage(String outgoing) {
  LoRa.beginPacket();                   // start packet
  LoRa.write(destination);              // add destination address
  LoRa.write(localAddress);             // add sender address
  LoRa.write(msgCount);                 // add message ID
  LoRa.write(outgoing.length());        // add payload length
  LoRa.print(outgoing);                 // add payload
  LoRa.endPacket();                     // finish packet and send it
  msgCount++;                           // increment message ID
}

void onReceive(int packetSize) {
  if (packetSize == 0) return;
  // read packet header bytes:
  int recipient = LoRa.read();          // recipient address
  byte sender = LoRa.read();            // sender address
  byte incomingMsgId = LoRa.read();     // incoming msg ID
  byte incomingLength = LoRa.read();    // incoming msg length
  // received a packet
  Serial.print("Received packet:  ");
  String LoRaData = LoRa.readString();
  Serial.print(LoRaData);
  // read packet
  while (LoRa.available()) {
    Serial.print((char)LoRa.read());
  }
  // print RSSI of packet
  Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
  Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
  delay(1000);
}
```

I got the code from a tutorial and changed it so it is used to test the module for 2-way communication. Earlier, I tried an example from the library "LoRa Sender" and "LoRa Receiver" and it works flawlessly, so this isn't a hardware issue as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Does the other Lora device has the opposite configuration of `byte localAddress = 0xBB;` and `byte destination = 0xFF;`? BTW, `random(50) + 300;` is not the 2-3 seconds as the comment said, it is 300-350 ms. To wait for 2-3 seconds, you need `random(1000) + 2000`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are not quite right in the code, but the main one is this: `interval = random(50) + 300; // 2-3 seconds` That's nowhere near 2 seconds. `interval` is in milliseconds, so a maximum of `50+300` will give you 0.35 seconds. Which means that both devices are transmitting NON-STOP, and can't hear each other. Try something like `2000 + random(1000)`... Although there are better ways to get a random than using `random`. But anyway.

Also, stay off 433e6, it's a busy frequency, and if there are people nearby with a car remote control, you'll receive a lot of stuff not from you.

Comment: Thank you man! The interval was the thing that messed it up.